# How to edit Custom.css file in Chrome OS?

Tags: unix, google-chrome-os

I have found several [interesting article](https://plus.google.com/100132233764003563318/posts/RcxgcETeo7c)s describing css tweaks to the Chrome OS operating system, but none of them add information how the files are actually editted. I have attempted to open the terminal and use every unix editor i could think of (vi, nano...), but i can't even navigate to the directories specified. Does anyone know how to edit the Custom.css file in the */home/chronos/user/User StyleSheets/* folder? Or any other system file? Can it even be done from within the Os itself? Thanks for your answers.

I am not in the dev or beta channel, if that matters.

Comment: which OS ? Linux or Unix? What happens when you issue the command `which vi`, `which nano`, etc on the terminal? Try using `find $HOME -name yourCSSfileName.css` and if it finds the file, then you can cd to that dir and use any editor that your found. Warning, if you haven't used vi before, you'll need a friend that does. It is not obvious to a casual user. Good luck.

Comment: **Chrome Os**, the Linux distro by google. The terminal seems very limited, though, so i assumed is was going for the wrong direction.

Comment: yes, sorry, it dawned on me after I posted that you had it tagged correctly. Please try the `which vi`, etc OR `cd /bin; ls -l OR cd /usr/bin ; ls -l` and see if you can find an editor there to use. These dirs should be standard, but as its chrome OS, it may be different. Ah,.. and you're looking for Custom.css? then `find / -name Custom.css`. This will search everyplace and may take some time, but if the file is there, that should find it. Good luck.

Comment: 'which', 'cd', 'ls', 'find', 'uname', 'set' are all returned as Unknown Commands. I suspect the terminal has some specific options only, but i can't find a list anywhere. Resources and documentation, besides standard user operations, seem to be very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received the answer from [François Beaufort](https://plus.google.com/100132233764003563318), and i thought it might help other people too.

```
It's relatively easy to do it actually.
Create your file "Custom.css" in another machine and download it in Downloads.
You just need to access the Shell by typing <Ctrl> <Alt> + t,
Then enter "shell" and press <Enter>,
Type "mv ~/User\ Stylesheets/Custom.css ~/User\ Stylesheets/Custom.css.bak" to save the current one in case and press <Enter>
Then type "cp ~/Downloads/Custom.css ~/User\ Stylesheets/" and press <Enter>
```

He add's:

```
you need to activate the developer mode: http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/cr-48-chrome-notebook-developer-information#TOC-Entering-Developer-Mode
```

François, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

From the article you posted

> Locate your Custom.css file in ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/User StyleSheets for **Ubuntu** or C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Default\User StyleSheets for **Windows** and insert these lines: . . .

So the Custom.css isn't in the appropriate directory?

What happens when you type `uname -a` in the terminal you're using? If you get something besides 'Bad command or filename', edit your post to include the output of `set` executed in your terminal.

I'm approaching this from the 'unix' tag point-of-view. Looking at the chomium-OS web page, I don't see any info on a terminal.

Comment: It's not the matter of not being in the proper directory. It's me not being able to even access that directory. I have attempted to use the commands you listed, but as above, they are all unknown.

Comment: So what sort of hardware are you using google-chrome-os on? Finally, what happens if you type `echo $SHELL` on your terminal. As this doesn't seem to be a unix-like system, unless there is a reasonable message there, I will be just be guessing too. Good luck.

Comment: [Samsung series 5](http://www.google.nl/intl/en/chromebook/#chromebooks-samsung). 'echo' also is an unknown command, however, the terminal has an 'help' option that i just noticed. It lists various commands that affect some sercurity cerificates and (3g)modem  interactions. I'm beginning to suspect the terminal is not the way to go here.